# how to authenticate a user using aws cognito in android

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using a code below to make it work on my website. How can I convert the following code into android?

COde :

```
    var authenticationData = {
            Username : 'username',
            Password : 'password',
        };

var identity_pool_id="dqdwrqw*******";
        var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
        var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
            ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
        };
        var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
        var userData = {
            Username : 'username',
            Pool : userPool
        };
        var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
                /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
                console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
            },

            onFailure: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            },

        });
```

Android code :

```
final CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "ap***",
                        Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1 
                );

                Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
                logins.put("Username", email);
                logins.put("Password", pass);
                credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

I don't know how to get data from this. Please help me out

Comment: The Cognito SDK for Android follows a similar structure than NodeJs.  So, why don’t you make a search in Amazon site about Cognito’s Java SDK

Comment: I did but I'm not getting anything that matches the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The easiest way for doing that is following the AWS documentation:**

- https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/resources/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples

A very important thing is switching from asynchronous to synchronous model.  In Android SDK you will need to rethink the way you’ve developed for Javascript.  However, like I said, the structure of the code will be very similar.

Do I try following the links above.

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question. The reason is that I have a complicated process configured using api gateway and user pools and groups. It would be great if I could just get the code above in android :)

Comment: @jason no, it didn’t.  The purpose of my answer is to open a path for researching,  you need to look for it because you don’t have a problem here, you want the code from scratch without any effort from you.  Therefore, keep your researching to accomplish your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Eleazar. I'll look into it and post the code here which is not working as I've tried to make it work :)

Comment: Good, that will help you more than I “did” so far.  :-)